# Removing files after deleting remote branch

Tags: git

I've deleted a remote branch with the following command:

```
git push le_remote :le_dead_branch
```

And the branch was removed with success on the remote. 
But after checking the size of the git repo I found out that probably the files, exclusive to that specific branch, were (probably) still there. This, so I believe, is due to the fact that what I've deleted was the ref to that specific state, but not the files, and my question is: how can I actually remove the files from the filesystem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to the remote repository and do

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git prune
git repack -a -d
```

Only then will the objects associated with that branch get pruned.